# How to prove convexity of that function of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, covariance, symmetric-matrices

Let $f(\Phi) = \|\Phi^{-1/2}a\|^{-2}_2=\left( a^T \Phi^{-1} a \right)^{-1}$ where
$\Phi \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a positive semi-definite normal matrix, e.g. a covariance matrix
$a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector

How to prove that $f$ is concave (that is, -$f$ is convex)?

Comment: Concave. That is -$f$ is convex. But not any matrix, should be a normal matrix and positive semi-definite.

Comment: A monte-carlo simulation in MATLAB shows that it's correct. Any idea how to prove tha?